# Remove all the text using sed

Tags: regex, sed, awk

Format:

[Headword]{}"UC(icl>restriction)"(Attributes);(gloss)

The testme.txt file has 2 lines

```
[testme] {} "acetify" (V,lnk,CJNCT,AJ-V,VINT,VOO,VOO-CHNG,TMP,Vo) <H,0,0>; 
[newtest] {} "acid-fast" (ADJ,DES,QUAL,TTSM) <H,0,0>;
```

The expected output is this:

```
testme = acetify
newtest = acid-fast
```

What I have achieved so far is:

cat testme.txt | sed 's/[//g' | sed 's/]//g' | sed 's/{}/=/g' | sed 's/\"//'

```
testme = acetify" (V,lnk,CJNCT,AJ-V,VINT,VOO,VOO-CHNG,TMP,Vo) <H,0,0>;
newtest = acid-fast" (ADJ,DES,QUAL,TTSM) <H,0,0>;
```

How do I remove all the text from the second " to the end of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove everything after the doublequote-space-openparenthesis `" (`:

```
sed 's/" (.*//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole process might be a little quicker with `awk`:

```
awk 'NF > 0 { print $1 " = " $3 }' testme.txt | tr -d '[]"'
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you do it with awk instead of all those `sed` commands, which is unnecessary. what you want is field 1 and field 3. use `gsub()` to remove the quotes and brackets

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\"/,"",$3);gsub(/\]|\[/,"",$1);print $1" = "$3}' file
testme = acetify
newtest = acid-fast
```

Answer (score 1):

Your whole sequence of multiple calls to `sed` can be replaced by:

```
sed 's/\[\([^]]*\)][^"]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1 = \2/' inputfile
```